# Error in Reflection

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

The purpose of the code is to take any given `String` and handle the three different cases.

1. "doSomething" => invoke `doSomething()`
2. "doSomethingElse,2" => invoke `doSomething(2)`
3. "doSomethingElsePlease,3,4" => invoke `doSomething(3,4)`

Number 2 and 3 can both be handled with `varargs` and passing the arguments as an `array`. Number 1 is were the problem occurs. The error that occurs is that

`h("doSomething");` is trying to call for `doSomething(null) {...}`

```
private void h (String abc) {       
    String method = (abc.indexOf(",") == -1) ? abc: abc.substring(0, abc.indexOf(","));
    System.out.println("Method: |" + method+"|");       
    String[] arguments = (abc.indexOf(",") == -1) ? null : abc.substring(abc.indexOf(",")).split(",");
    System.out.println("Arguments: " + Arrays.toString(arguments));

    try {
        if (arguments == null) {
            this.getClass().getMethod(method, String.class).invoke(this); 
        } else {
            System.exit(0);
            this.getClass().getMethod(method, String.class).invoke(this, Arrays.asList(arguments)); 
        }           
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
            | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
            | SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is the code that I was given for `h`

```
private void h (String s) {
    System.out.println("Event: " + s);
    String[] a = s.split(",");

    switch (a.length){
        case 1:
            try {
                this.getClass().getMethod(s).invoke(this);
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
                nsme.printStackTrace();         
            } catch (IllegalAccessException iae) {
                iae.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException ite) {
                ite.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;

        case 2: //Method with string parameter
            try {
                this.getClass().getMethod(a[0], String.class).invoke(this, a[1]); //ex: methodName = a[0]  stringArg = a[1],  methodName(stringArg);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                    | InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException
                    | SecurityException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Which is working expect that it can only handle one argument. I also wanted to improve the code overall by rewriting some parts.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. (It's not at all clear whether the problem is in `h` or how you're calling `h`....) Additionally, any code *after* `System.exit(0)` is unlikely to execute...

Comment: Have you tried `this.getClass().getMethod(method).invoke(this);` (remove the `String.class`) or perhaps replace it with `null`.

Comment: Just did that. Before I replied I wanted to read up what it did. Now I know and it is working. The `Sytem.exit(0)` was just for debug purposes and did not change anything that happened in the code. The `String.class` defines the arguments I take it?

Comment: Yeah I will quote the javadoc in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting to the javadoc of `getMethod` from [`Class`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-):

> ```
> public Method getMethod(String name,
>                         Class<?>... parameterTypes)
>                  throws NoSuchMethodException,
>                         SecurityException
> ```
>
> Returns a Method object that reflects the specified public member method of the class or interface represented by this Class object. The name parameter is a String specifying the simple name of the desired method. **The parameterTypes parameter is an array of Class objects that identify the method's formal parameter types, in declared order. If parameterTypes is null, it is treated as if it were an empty array**.

So if you want to be calling a 0 parameter method you need to supply either `null` or no arguments to `getMethod`:

```
this.getClass().getMethod(method).invoke(this);
```

Methods that have a `String` as a parameter can be called as you showed:

```
this.getClass().getMethod(method, String.class).invoke(this, Arrays.asList(arguments));
```

In order to formulate a full `getMethod` with *multiple parameters* you need to establish what the method requires:

> "an array of Class objects".

You might need to include in the `h` method a String list of parameter *types* (i.e. `String`, `Integer`, `Double`) along with the actual arguments.  Then you can use the [`Class.forName(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)) to get the actual `Class` object defined from each parameter type String.  Once the list is complete you can pass it in to the `getMethod` class:

```
this.getClass().getMethod(method, classList).invoke(this, Arrays.asList(arguments));
```